# Hiding xAxis labels when using Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using chart.js to create a linegraph from data in a locally hosted mysql DB.

I am able to pull this data and display it as intended, however despite following documentation and advice given else where I am unable to hide the xAxis Labels. The code I am using is below - any help would be much appriacated.

```
            var chardata = {
            labels: time,
            datasets: [
                {
                label: "System health",
                fill: false,
                backgroundColor: "rgba(123, 192, 67, 0.75)",
                borderColor: "rgba(123, 192, 67, 1)",
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(123, 192, 67, 1)",
                pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(123, 192, 67, 1)",
                data: health_score
                }
            ]
        };

        var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

        var options = {
            type: 'line',
            data: chardata,
            options: {
                scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        display: false
                    }
                }]
                }
            }
        };

        var LineGraph = new Chart(ctx, options);
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

..

```
var options = {
    type: 'line',
    data: chardata,
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                display: false,
                ticks: {
                    display: false
                }
            }]
        }
    }
};
```

..

Comment: I added this line, however the x axis labels are still showing.

Comment: I've wrote a demo on codepan, check it. https://codepen.io/tanhaican/pen/MWaYqWY

Comment: BTW, Chart.js is a very good tool for charts, but the api document is hard for me, I'd prefer echart.js.